# fedora 25 sssd active directory user cannot logon

Tags: linux, active-directory, fedora, sssd

I have a Fedora 25 workstation (Korora 25 actually). I have configured and joined to my Active Directory domain with sssd/realmd as I have done many times before. I have successfully done this with Centos 6/7 and Korora 24. Now with 25 I cannot log on with my AD users. Either locally or via SSH (yes sshd is started).

I have verified the sssd.conf file is correct. I disabled the new GPO integration. I have never had to mess with krb5.conf or smb.conf before to get this to work.

I have verified that all services are started.

sssd logs are empty.

I know there have been some new features added to SSSD so I think I am missing something here. Have searched the internet and can't fine anything that works.

```
sssd.conf
[sssd]
domains = BBIIUS.NET
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/BBIIUS.NET]
ad_domain = BBIIUS.NET
krb5_realm = BBIIUS.NET
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
ad_gpo_access_control = disabled
```

Comment: Does your DNS work?

Comment: yes, DNS works fine. Join to domain works fine which would not work if DNS was broken. it is login on after join that is not working.

Comment: OK, I have been struggling with this for a week and today it starts working. I have no idea what I did. The only change I made to the system was to add debug_level = 9 to the sssd.conf file this morning.